# Conditional update either column1 or column2 or column3

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a SQL update statement like

```
UPDATE p
SET CASE WHEN inv.name='your' THEN p.your_qty=inv.qty
    CASE WHEN inv.name='other' THEN p.other_qty=inv.qty
    CASE WHEN inv.name='my' THEN p.my_qty=inv.qty
FROM products p
JOIN Qty_products_inv inv
ON p.itemNo= inv.itemNo
```

Comment: `CASE` is an expression, not a logical flow operator, it can't be used like the above.

Comment: Ya I know that I want to write query by which I can fulfill my goal, it is a query for understand my problem.

Comment: @marc_s Three updates, without the IF statements, with name=? in WHERE clauses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update all three columns.  `SET` can ***not*** update different columns on different rows.

So, pivot your source before joining, then set each column back to its existing value if there is no new value to pick up...

```
UPDATE
  p
SET
  your_qty  = COALESCE(inv.your_qty , p.your_qty ),
  other_qty = COALESCE(inv.other_qty, p.other_qty),
  my_qty    = COALESCE(inv.my_qty   , p.my_qty   )
FROM
  products p
JOIN
(
  SELECT
    itemNo,
    MAX(CASE WHEN name='your'  THEN qty END) AS your_qty,
    MAX(CASE WHEN name='other' THEN qty END) AS other_qty,
    MAX(CASE WHEN name='my'    THEN qty END) AS my_qty
  FROM
    qty_products_inv
  GROUP BY
    itemNo
)
  inv
    ON p.itemNo = inv.itemNo
```

Apologies for typos I'm on my phone.

***EDIT:***

**Don't do the following**, from my original answer, as @JonArmstrong's comment shows it does not work *(unless each row is only ever picking up one single change)*.

```
UPDATE
  p
SET
  your_qty  = CASE WHEN inv.name='your'  THEN inv.qty ELSE p.your_qty  END,
  other_qty = CASE WHEN inv.name='other' THEN inv.qty ELSE p.other_qty END,
  my_qty    = CASE WHEN inv.name='my'    THEN inv.qty ELSE p.my_qty    END
FROM
  products p
JOIN
  qty_products_inv inv
    ON p.itemNo = inv.itemNo
```

Comment: Probably best to use the second approach and not potentially try to touch any `products` rows more than once in an `UPDATE`.  See the following results of the above approaches with a little sample data.  Carefully compare the differences in the result: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a9ac5d44e49b8ab65e7ba8a906eb67b7   There are some other issues as well, depending on existing constraints.